# Why can std::move_iterator advertise itself as a forward (or stronger) iterator, when it dereferences to an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to cppreference, [`std::move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) sets its `::iterator_category` to the category of its underlying iterator<sup>1</sup>.

But I reckon it can be an input/output iterator at best, since for [forward iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) `reference` must be an lvalue reference, while `move_iterator` sets `reference` (and the return type of `operator*`) to an rvalue reference<sup>2</sup>.

Is this a blatant mistagging of the iterator with a wrong category?

Being able to do this for my own iterators is undoubtedly convenient. Is there any reason I shouldn't do this, if even the standard library does so?

---

<sup>1</sup> But anything stronger than `random_access_iterator_tag` is truncated to `random_access_iterator_tag`, which is weird, since `contiguous_iterator_tag` is only supposed to be used for `::iterator_concept`.

<sup>2</sup> Or leaves it untouched if it's not a reference, but then the underlying iterator shouldn't advertise itself as a forward iterator either.

Comment: This is [LWG1211](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1211) and the main reason is the performance.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I understand that this is good for performance, but this DR is marked as "Resolved", and I'm not entirely sure what the "resolution" was, if the latest standard still does this.

Comment: That is, it was *resolved* by [N3066](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3066.html), which still makes `move_iterator` a valid forward iterator.

Comment: It should be noted that C++23 also fixes the `iterator_concept` of `move_iterator` so that it is no longer always `input_iterator_tag`, see [P2520](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2520r0.html) for intention.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yes, I've seen the link to N3066 in the defect report you linked, but I'm unsure how exactly `move_iterator` became a valid forward iterator. So far my best theory is that cppreference is wrong, and `reference` must be any reference, not specifically an lvalue reference.

Comment: "*So far my best theory is that cppreference is wrong, and reference must be any reference, not specifically an lvalue reference.*" Where does cppreference require that the `reference` must be an lvalue reference? Are you referring to that exposition-only concept `__LegacyForwardIterator`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator

Comment: "*The type `std::iterator_traits<It>::reference` must be exactly...*" Yes, that part is absolutely wrong. The correct description is from [forward.iterators-1.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterators#forward.iterators-1.3): "*if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a constant iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`*", which doesn't exclude rvalue references.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Do you want to post an answer, or should I do it?

Comment: You can make it a self-answered question. I'm not good at the language-lawyer question, which is why I only comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On one hand, the cppreference article on [forward iterator requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator) was wrong (already fixed by someone). `reference` must be *any* reference (`&` or `&&`), not specifically lvalue reference (`&`). Meaning `move_iterator` does conform.

But on the other hand, auto-determining `::iterator_category` [uses different wording](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.traits#concept:cpp17-forward-iterator), which only permits lvalue references:

> ```
> concept cpp17-forward-iterator = ... && is_lvalue_reference_v<iter_reference_t<I>>
> ```

This looks like a standard defect (and was eventually fixed by LWG [3798](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3798)).

---

Sources for forward iterators being able to use any kind of reference:

[`[forward.iterators]/1.3`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterators#forward.iterators-1.3):

> if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a constant iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`

See also [LWG1211](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1211) (from 2009), which raised the same issue, and was resolved by [N3066](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3066.html) (in 2010), which changed the wording from "lvalue reference" to "any reference". (Thanks @康桓瑋 for the links).